# Deployment of VM workers running an C++ executable on Azure

Tags: c++, azure, cloud, scaling

I am presented with a program developed in c++ that implements a compute intensive algorithm that uses  mpi to achieve better results. The executable has been tested on a single VM with 16 cores on Azure and the results have been satisfying. Now we need to test its performance and its scalability on 64 or 128 cores. As far as I know , a single VM can't employ more than 16 cores , so I think I need to implement a set of VMs that will execute the computation, but I don't know where to start with the deployment and the communication among the VMs. Any guidance or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: First, do take a look at `G Series VMs` which are announced recently. They can have up to 32 cores (still not 64 or 128 cores but better than 16 you have currently) - http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/20/azures-getting-bigger-faster-and-more-open/. Also can you describe more about communication requirement between VMs. You may also want to look at Azure Batch Service which is announced recently - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/batch/.

Comment: @GauravMantri I don't have the source code of the program but I know that it was implemented with MPI. What is needed in order to achieve an execution that will use cores on more than one VM?

Comment: You'll have to somehow configure MPI to make all those VMs connected into one MPI cluster. Should not differ much from doing the same for hardware servers.

Comment: @sharptooth Where should the configuration of the MPI into a cluster take place? I don't think that the source code of the program will be available to me , so i'd like to do this externally.

Comment: @helplessKirk: Well, there're various MPI environments, mpich is one of them. Before you can run anything using mpich you have to install and configure it. I'd guess nothing prevents you from installing it and proper configuring it on Azure VMs.